# regular expression to split string using keywords

Tags: java, regex

I've been trying to build a pattern in Java to split the following string by comma , double quotes and by and word.

for example :

Input string :

```
String str = "\"java and c++\" and ruby , are languages";
```

I want result as :

```
["java and c++",
ruby,
are languages]
```

Input string :

String str = "\"java and c++\" and \"ruby\" and are languages";

I want result as :

```
["java and c++",
"ruby",
are languages]
```

Input string :

String str = "java and c++ ,\"ruby\" and are languages";

I want result as :

```
[java and c++,
"ruby",
are languages]
```

I want single pattern to achieve all the results.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way ;

```
String str = "\"java and c++\" and ruby , are languages";
str = str.replaceAll("and(?=[^\"\"]*\")", "#");

List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : str.split("and|,")) {
    result.add(s.replaceAll("#", "and"));
}
System.out.println(result);
```

The idea is :

1. replace the **and** between quotes `".. and .."` with `str.replaceAll("and(?=[^\"\"]*\")", "#")`
2. split with `and` and `,` `str.split("and|,")`
3. replace the `#` with `and` in then end.

This will print :

```
["java and c++" ,  ruby ,  are languages]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to split by `"java and c++"` and keep it in the result (by default, delimiters are not included in the result), you need to include `lookahead` with it, and use comma as second delimiter, e.g.:

```
String str = "\"java and c++\" and ruby , are languages";

String quote = Pattern.quote("\"java and c++\"");

String[] split = str.split("((?<=" + quote + ")|,)");

System.out.println(split.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
```

This will match `"java and c++"` and include it in the result (as a result of lookahead) it will also match `,` but won't include it in the result.